# If $Y = g(X)$, why is $f_Y(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_Y(x)$

Tags: probability

I'm looking at a derivation for the PDF of $g(X)$.

It defines $Y = g(X)$, and then notes that
$$
f_Y(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_Y(x)
$$

I am confused about several things here. I know that $Y$ is written as some function of $X$, but isn't it conventional for the PDF of $Y$ to take in $y$ as an argument? Here, we take in $x$, which confuses me. Is there some form of chain rule that's being applied here?

If I were to start this problem, I would have probably tried to do

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} P(Y \leq y) \\
= \frac{d}{dy}P(g(X) \leq g(x)) \\
= \frac{d}{dy}P(X \leq x) \\
= \frac{d}{dy} F_X(x) \\
= f_X(x) * \frac{dx}{dy}
$$

We know $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dg(x)}{dx} = g'(x) \implies \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{g'(x)}$,

so
$$
f_Y(y) = f_X(x) / g'(x) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) / g'(g^{-1}(y))
$$

The given answer is:

[image]

Is this equivalent to what I derived?

Answer (score 1):

$x$, $y$ are just tokens used as arguments of the function.   They do not *have* to match the symbols used for the random variables.   That is just convenience.   It is quite permissible to use different letters should you wish..

$$\begin{align}f_{\small Y}(t)&=\dfrac{\mathrm d\,F_{\small Y}(t)}{\mathrm d\,t\hspace{4ex}}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d\,\mathsf P(Y\leq t)}{\mathrm d\,t\hspace{8ex}}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d\,\mathsf P(g(X)\leq t)}{\mathrm d\, t\hspace{11ex}}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d\,\mathsf P(X\leq g^{-1}(t))}{\mathrm d\, t\hspace{13ex}}&~\star~&\small\text{if $g$ is invertable and strictly increasing}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d\,F_X(g^{-1}(t))}{\mathrm d\,t\hspace{10ex}}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d\,g^{-1}(t)}{\mathrm d\, t\hspace{5ex}}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d\,F_{\small X}(g^{-1}(t)) }{\mathrm d\, g^{-1}(t)\hspace{5ex}}\\&=\dfrac{\mathrm d\,g^{-1}(t)}{\mathrm d\, t\hspace{5ex}}\cdot f_{\small X}(g^{-1}(t))\end{align}$$

And so : $$f_{\small Y}(y) = \dfrac{\mathrm d\,g^{-1}(y)}{\mathrm d\, y\hspace{5ex}}\cdot f_{\small X}(g^{-1}(y))$$

Or

$$f_{\small Y}(x) = \dfrac{\mathrm d\,g^{-1}(x)}{\mathrm d\, x\hspace{5ex}}\cdot f_{\small X}(g^{-1}(x))$$

Or

$$f_{\small Y}(\xi) = \dfrac{\mathrm d\,g^{-1}(\xi)}{\mathrm d\, \xi\hspace{5ex}}\cdot f_{\small X}(g^{-1}(\xi))$$

Comment: Ah I see. In my derivation, but in my derivation, I obtained $f_X(g^{-1}(y)) / g'(g^{-1}(y))$. Is this equivalent to yours?

Comment: Alternatively, I could've done something different for $\frac{dx}{dy}$. I could do $x = g^{-1}(y)$ and then see that $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy}$, which gives us what you have.

Comment: Let's see.  You have $\dfrac{\mathrm d g^{-1}(y)}{\mathrm d y}=\left.\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d g(x)}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{-1}\right\rvert_{x:=g^{-1}(y)} = \dfrac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}$ .  A little obscure, but correct.

Comment: What if $g(x)$ here was only increasing and not strictly increasing? A unique solution wouldn't exist?

Comment: $g$ would not be invertable were an interval to map to the same value.

Comment: Ah I see. It seems if $g$ was strictly *decreasing*, it would just be the same result, but negated. So the strictly increasing/decreasing nature of this function seems to only change the sign of the pdf

Comment: Yes.  In such case the only requirement is that $g$ is invertable (at least over the support for $f_{\small X}$). We place an absolute value sign around the derivative to ensure the pdf is non-negative, as a good pdf should be.$$f_{\small Y}(y)= \begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\mathrm d\,g^{-1}(y)}{\mathrm d\,y}\end{vmatrix}\cdot f_{\small X}(g^{-1}(y))$$